# jQuery how to replace text node for children of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all text of children of elements.

such as this, I replace all text children of `II`.Maybe has other tag.
not only `<ul>` and `<li>`.

- I
- II

  1. A
  2. B

     - 1
     - 2
     - 3
  3. C
- III

I want get like this:

- I
- II

  1. test: A
  2. test: B

     - test: 1
     - test: 2
     - test: 3
  3. test: C
- III

I try code it, but I fail.

Why the `.find('*')` is failure?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li class="item-a">A</li>
            <li class="item-b">B
                <ul class="level-3">
                    <li class="item-1">1</li>
                    <li class="item-2">2</li>
                    <li class="item-3">3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-c">C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>

<!--I want get like this:-->
<!--<ul class="level-1">-->
    <!--<li class="item-i">I</li>-->
    <!--<li class="item-ii">II-->
        <!--<ul class="level-2">-->
            <!--<li class="item-a">test: A</li>-->
            <!--<li class="item-b">test: B-->
                <!--<ul class="level-3">-->
                    <!--<li class="item-1">test: 1</li>-->
                    <!--<li class="item-2">test: 2</li>-->
                    <!--<li class="item-3">test: 3</li>-->
                <!--</ul>-->
            <!--</li>-->
            <!--<li class="item-c">test: C</li>-->
        <!--</ul>-->
    <!--</li>-->
    <!--<li class="item-iii">III</li>-->
<!--</ul>-->
<script>
    $('ul.level-2').find('*').filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3
    }).each(function () {
        this.textContent = 'test:' + this.textContent;
    });
//    $('ul.level-2').children().filter(function () {
//        return this.nodeType === 3
//    }).each(function () {
//        this.textContent = 'test:' + this.textContent;
//    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not modify this HTML because it is not the code I wrote.
so I use js to modify it.

Thank!

## update

I solve it, Thank anyone!

Text Node is not a `Elements`, so `find('*')` can not **capture** it. I find `contents()` can **capture** it.
This is My code

```
    $('ul.level-2').find('*').contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && !!this.textContent.trim();
    }).each(function () {
        this.textContent = 'test'+this.textContent
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is recursion:

```
function recursivelyChangeText($node, transformFunc) {
  var children = $node.children()
  if(children.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { 
      recursivelyChangeText($(children[i]), transformFunc)
    }
  } else {
    $node.text(transformFunc($node.text()))
  }
}

recursivelyChangeText($('ul.level-2'), function(text) {
  return `test: ${text}`
})
```

here's a codepen: 
[SO Answer - Recursively Change Dom Content with jQuery](https://codepen.io/mattblackdev/pen/rYRbOJ/) by Matt Black ([@mattblackdev](https://codepen.io/mattblackdev)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: recursion is a good idea! Thank! But, why the `.find('*')` is failure?

Comment: oh! I solve it! Text Node is not a `Elements`, so `find('*')` can not **capture** it. I find `contents()` can **capture** it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.level-2').find('li').toArray().forEach(function(e){
    e.innerHTML = 'test ' + e.innerHTML;
});

$('.level-3').find('li').toArray().forEach(function(e){
    e.innerHTML = 'test ' + e.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: not only `<li>`, maybe has other tag. so I try use `find('*')`.